# Recursive equation answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the following recursive equations:

$$3A_n = 2A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}$$

$$3B_n = A_{n-1}+2B_{n-1}$$

Let $A_0=2$ and $B_0=-1$. I know there are supposed to be different ways to solve this but I was thinking about solving one equation and replace it in the other to find the final answer I tried but I couldn't find the result I will be glad if you help me. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note:  $A_n+B_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}$

Comment: Also, note that $A_n-B_n = \frac{1}{3}(A_{n-1}-B_{n-1})$

Comment: From the first equation, you can find a value for $ B _ { n - 1 } $ in terms of $ A _ n $ and $ A _ { n - 1 } $. Use that to write the second equation only in term of $ A _ { n + 1 } $, $ A _ n $ and $ A _ { n - 1 } $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the observation by J. W. Tanner in the comments, you can reduce the problem to a single first-order recurrence: $A_n+B_n$ is constant as $n$ varies, so $A_n+B_n=A_0+B_0=1$ for all $n\ge 0$. Thus, $3A_n=2A_{n-1}+1-A_{n-1}=A_{n-1}+1$, and we have the recurrence

$$A_n=\frac13A_{n-1}+\frac13\;,$$

which is easily solved in a variety of ways. E.g., let $x_n=A_n-d$ for some $d$ as yet to be determined; then

$$x_n+d=\frac13(x_{n-1}+d)+\frac13\;,$$

so

$$x_n=\frac13x_{n-1}-\frac{2d}3+\frac13=\frac13x_{n-1}$$

if we set $d=\frac12$. It is then immediate that

$$x_n=x_0\left(\frac13\right)^n=(A_0-d)\left(\frac13\right)^n=\frac32\left(\frac13\right)^n=\frac1{2\cdot3^{n-1}}$$

for $n\ge 0$ and hence that

$$A_n=x_n+d=\frac1{2\cdot3^{n-1}}+\frac12=\frac12\left(1+\frac1{3^{n-1}}\right)$$

for $n\ge 0$. Finally,

$$B_n=1-A_n=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{3^{n-1}}\right)\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let us try your idea. From the first equation, we get

$$B_{n-1}=3A_n-2A_{n-1},$$ which we plug in the second, giving

$$3(3A_{n+1}-2A_n)=A_{n-1}+2(3A_{n}-2A_{n-1})$$

or

$$3A_{n+1}-4A_n+A_{n-1}=0.$$

The characteristic polynomial has the roots $1$ and $\dfrac13$. From the general expression of $A_n$ you can draw $B_n$. Finally, the indeterminate constants are found from the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_n=\begin{bmatrix}A_n\\B_n\end{bmatrix}$, then the system can be written as
$$v_{n}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \end{bmatrix} v_{n-1}=Av_{n-1}$$
So,
\begin{align*}
v_{n}&=Av_{n-1}\\
&=A(Av_{n-2})=A^2v_{n-2}\\
\vdots &=\vdots\\
v_{n}&=A^{n}v_{0}.
\end{align*}
This (stochastic) matrix $A$ has two eigen values $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{3}$ so it is diagonalizable, i.e. $A=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}$, where $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Now we can use
$$v_{n}=A^{n}v_{0} \implies v_n=PD^nP^{-1}v_0=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{3^n}\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
which solve the system completely.